# Laravel joins not working on 3 different tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Model**

```
Album::join('tracks', 'albums.track_id', '=', 'tracks.id')
        ->join('singers', 'tracks.singer_id', '=', 'singers.id')->get();
```

**Snigers table**

```
id - int
name - string
```

**Tracks table**

```
id -int
name - string
singers_id - JSON // example["1","2"]
```

**Album table**

```
id - int
name - string
tracks_id - JSON // example ["1","2"]
```

**here first singers table after track table reference array of id multiple and next alums table reference track table id is also array.how to joins this three table**

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use joins here, if you have a pivot table for these, here's what you can simply do:

In your models you can simply create a relation like this:

`Album` Model:

```
public function tracks() {
    return $this->hasMany(Track::class);
}

public function singers() {
    return $this->hasMany(Singer::class);
}
```

and then call it in your controller.

`AlbumController.php`

```
Album::where('id',1)->with('tracks','singers');
```

This will simply fetch all the records with Tracks and Singers that belong to Album id 1.